# Json filling in trigger

Tags: postgresql, trigger, functions

Good afternoon There is a label in which records are added. Each entry has a json column. Json has several 6 fields. When adding a new record, the data from it may refer to the old record. It is necessary to catch this with a trigger and fill in from the old record.

My code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION insert_customized_agreement_list_item_row() RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
    DECLARE
        object jsonb;
    BEGIN
        UPDATE customized_agreement_list_item SET event = 'deleted' WHERE agreement_id = NEW.agreement_id;
        NEW.row_id = nextval('shared_row_id_seq');
        NEW.last_modified = now();
        
        object = NEW.object;

        IF (object #>> '{customized_agreement_list_item, body, color}') IS NULL THEN
            object = jsonb_set(object, '{customized_agreement_list_item, body, color}', OLD.object #> '{customized_agreement_list_item, body, color}');

        END IF;
        IF (object #>> '{customized_agreement_list_item, body, custom_name}') IS NULL THEN
    object = jsonb_set(object, '{customized_agreement_list_item, body, custom_name}', OLD.object #> '{customized_agreement_list_item, body, custom_name}');
        END IF;
        IF (object #>> '{customized_agreement_list_item, body, custom_rank}') IS NULL THEN
    object = jsonb_set(object, '{customized_agreement_list_item, body, custom_rank}', OLD.object #> '{customized_agreement_list_item, body, custom_rank}');
        END IF;
        IF (object #>> '{customized_agreement_list_item, body, is_hidden}') IS NULL THEN
    object = jsonb_set(object, '{customized_agreement_list_item, body, is_hidden}', OLD.object #> '{customized_agreement_list_item, body, is_hidden}');
        END IF;
        IF (object #>> '{customized_agreement_list_item, body, klogin}') IS NULL THEN
    object = jsonb_set(object, '{customized_agreement_list_item, body, klogin}', OLD.object #> '{customized_agreement_list_item, body, klogin}');
        END IF;
        IF (object #>> '{customized_agreement_list_item, body, subject_id}') IS NULL THEN
    object = jsonb_set(object, '{customized_agreement_list_item, body, subject_id}', OLD.object #> '{customized_agreement_list_item, body, subject_id}');
        END IF;
        
        NEW.object = object;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$;
```

But it doesn't work. The data from the old record does not go to the new one. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the variable assignment you are using is incorrect for example:

```
object = NEW.object;
```

The correct way of assigning the variable is:

```
object := NEW.object;
```

For more information on this check out the Postgres docs - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html

Also, make sure that you have registered the trigger using the below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER json_filling_in_trigger AFTER INSERT ON <TABLE NAME>
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION insert_customized_agreement_list_item_row();
```

Please ensure you fill in the correct table name.

The docs on registering the triggers can be found here - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html

Hope that helps.